# Function operator check if the first function argument is empty df

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I have a function operator to handle plot errors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
    tryCatch(
        f,
        error = function(e) plot_error(e)
    )
}

plot_error <- function(error) {
    ggplot(
        tibble(text = str_wrap(error, 80)),
        aes(x = 1, y = 1, label = text)
    ) +
        geom_text(color = "red") +
        theme_void()
}
```

I also have a function to create plot facets:

```
plot_facet <- function(df) { 
    df %>% 
        ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
        geom_line() + 
        facet_grid(~am) 
}
```

It can happen that `plot_facet` receives an empty dataframe for input:

```
handle_plot_error(plot_facet(tibble()))
```

This error doesn't get handled by my function so I would like improve `handle_plot_error` to include something like:

```
if(nrow(df) == 0) { 
    stop("No data available")
}
```

and then pass this error message to `plot_error` function.
I know I could include `stop` case into the `plot_facet` but I prefer it to be in `handle_plot_error` since I use it for a lot of plotting functions.

Maybe this can be helpful: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-operators.html

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. `handle_plot_error` works as a function operator for plotting functions and catches possible plotting errors and displays them on plots (I use it on Shiny).

Comment: It just came to my mind that the main purpose for your `handle_plot_error` function is to display meaningful error messages in a shiny app. Otherwise you probably wouldn’t need to print the error inside a ggplot2 plot. If your use case is a shiny app, then you‘d be better off using `validate(need())`. Especially if your `data.frame` is a user input you can easily check if `nrow(df)== 0` and the error will be shown in your plots (and all reactivity downstream will be stopped).

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't catch the error because it occurs only when the plot is build for printing. If you don't want to call `print` explicitly, as in `handle_plot_error(print(plot_facet(tibble())))`, you need to build the plot within your `tryCatch`.

```
handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
  tryCatch({
    ggplot_build(f)
    f
    },
    error = function(e) plot_error(e)
  )
}
```

That's a bit inefficient for large and complex plots.

*Edit:*

You can easily access and test the data of a ggplot object.

```
handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
  tryCatch({
    stopifnot("Data.frame is empty!" = nrow(f$data) > 0)
    ggplot_build(f)
    f
    },
    error = function(e) plot_error(e)
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but I'd like to know if it's possible to check (`if(nrow(df)) == 0`) the first argument of the function `f` that gets passed to `handle_plot_error` so I could print a more intuitive error message?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a check `nrow(df) == 0` function and then include it in the `tryCatch`.

Your original `handle_plot_error` function is not a function operator yet, since function operators take a function as input and return a function as output. This is why I changed the `handle_plot_error` by wrapping `function(…) {}` around `tryCatch` to make it a similar function operator like `purrr::possibly`. Then you either wrap the function that you want to be handled and then call the arguments like in `handle_plot_error(plot_facet)(mtcars)` or you define a handled version of your function `try_plot_facet <- handle_plot_error(plot_facet)` and can then call it in a regular way `try_plot_facet(mtcars)`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

check_df <- function(df) {
  if(nrow(df) == 0) { 
    rlang::abort("No data available") # `abort` has nicer error messages
  }
}

handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
  function(...){ 
  tryCatch({
    check_df(...)
    ggplot_build(f(...))
  },
  error = function(e) plot_error(e)
  )
  }
}

plot_error <- function(error) {
  plot <- ggplot(
    tibble(text = stringr::str_wrap(error, 80)),
    aes(x = 1, y = 1, label = text)
  ) +
    geom_text(color = "red") +
    theme_void()
  
  list(plot = plot)
}

plot_facet <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_grid(~am) 
} 

handle_plot_error(plot_facet)(tibble())
handle_plot_error(plot_facet)(mtcars)
```

If you have more than one argument in `plot_facet` we can Name them explicitly in our error handling function:

```
handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
  function(df, ...){ 
    tryCatch({
      check_df(df)
      ggplot_build(f(df, ...))
    },
    error = function(e) plot_error(e)
    )
  }
}

plot_facet <- function(df, var) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes({{var}}, mpg)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_grid(~am) 
} 

handle_plot_error(plot_facet)(tibble())
handle_plot_error(plot_facet)(mtcars, cyl)
```

Comment: I guess you don't need `check_df()` inside `plot_facet` then? Hoes it work for multiple arguments for `plot_facet`?

Comment: @mihagazvoda: yes `check_df()` inside `plot_facet` is not needed. I just forgot to delete it and now corrected the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed my second question has a typo. :D 
What to do in case `plot_facet` has multiple arguments?

Comment: @mihagazvoda: It depends on the kind of argument, is it a string or a bare variable name? Maybe you can post an example. My answer here was more to point out how a real function operator as defined in "Advanced R" looks like. Not using a function operator might be easier, as  suggested in Roland 's answer.

Comment: @mihagazvoda: See my updated answer with two arguments.

Comment: Thanks! So it's not possible to grab the argument by position? Because want to pass different functions to `plot_facet` that have different arguments but data is always the first one.

Comment: @mihagazvoda: I assume you mean you want to pass different functions to `handle_plot_error`. I think ist not possible to pass the arguments by position in the function operator, but I would need to see an example of what you have in mind. We could make use of more argument names, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland says, the error happens when building.  His solution is probably best because it will catch other kinds of errors besides just zero rows.  But if you really want to give a special error message for those, you can look at the result of the plot expression and see if the included `data` component has zero rows.  For example,

```
handle_plot_error <- function(f) {
  tryCatch({
    if (!inherits(f, "ggplot"))
       stop("You need to construct a plot.",
            call. = FALSE)
    if (nrow(f$data) == 0)
       stop("Dataset must have at least one row",
            call. = FALSE)
    f
    },
    error = function(e) plot_error(e)
  )
}
```

You could do both approaches by calling `ggplot_build` after the checks.